# Dealing with asterisks in Sphinx results

Tags: mysql, search, search-engine, sphinx

I'm using Sphinx to search MySQL.

One of the results Sphinx returns for a search is `M*A*S*H`, as in the hit television show.

[image]

The problem I'm facing is that `M*A*S*H` is returned for nearly any query made with Sphinx. **I'm guessing this is due to the asterisks.** If not, then what could the problem be?

**If the asterisks are causing my problem, how can I work around this to not have `M*A*S*H` returned for every query?**

Comment: Could you post your sphinx.conf? Perhaps it's something amiss with the way the indexes have been set up. It would be nice to have some sample data (even if it's only the row with M*A*S*H) and queries as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that asterisks are included in the charset_table.

```
charset_table = <blah blah blah>, U+002A
```

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-charset-table

Comment: Ah, yeah. That makes complete sense. I had just recently had to add ` U+0027` to `ignore_chars`, too.

Answer (score 0):

Does [this Sphinx function (EscapeString)](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#api-func-escapestring) do what you want

Comment: I don't believe so. The problem is not the query, it's the results sets returned. There's nothing that needs escaped.

Answer (score 0):

This problem no longer seems to exist, though I don't know why. I'm sure that something must have been amiss in my sphinx.conf. If someone else has this issue, let me know here and I'll try to update this answer accordingly.

Comment: Probably because before you had "enable_star = 1" and now you don't :-)

Comment: @Rafa, I still have `enable_star = 1`. @Riedsio's answer is the right one, methinks.

Comment: Josh> Yes Riedsio's seems like the correct answer. I was just guessing why your problem had disappeared without doing any apparent changes. Just ignore me :)

Comment: @Rafa Yeah, I realized just that after I posted my comment. My bad. No idea why it resolved itself, but that's life!

Answer (score 0):

In any case you can use the exceptions file to specify any word you may want to include in your searches. Remember to reindex whenever you change the file.

You can read the details here: http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/1.10/conf-exceptions.html